# Переход на другую страницу

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Доброго времени суток форумчане. Я начинающий программист под android, можно сказать нуб. Ну вот в чем вопрос, необходимо по нажатию кнопки перейти на другую страницу. Я создала два класса и две activity, соответственно две кнопки перехода на следующую страницу и обратно. Не знаю как описать это событие нажатия кнопки. Помогите умные люди. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnId);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```

А еще лучше взять и почитать какую-нибудь книжку по теме :)

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, AnyActivity.class));
```

а вообще стоило бы хоть пару уроков почитать [startandroid.ru](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom)